# Why doesn't `seq 100 | ( head -n1; tail -n1 )` work on Mac OSX?

Tags: bash, pipe, seq

The following command *should* print the first and last line from `seq 100`, but it only prints the first line:

```
seq 100 | (head -n1 ; tail -n1)
1
```

It does work for larger sequences, such as 10,000:

```
seq 10000 | (head -n1 ; tail -n1)
1
10000
```

### UPDATE

I've selected @John1024's answer because my question was *why* doesn't this work and he provides an acceptable answer.

Also, the *should* is apparently my opinion only..the reality is that `head` doesn't work this way...it may very well consume more stdin than I'd like, and leave nothing for `tail`.

Of course, the problem that prompted this question in the first palce was trying to read the first and last n lines of a file. Here's the solution I came up with based on GNU `sed`:

```
sed -ne'1,9{p;b}' -e'10{x;s/$/--/;x;G;p;b}' -e':a;$p;N;21,$D;ba'
```

or more compact

```
sed -ne'1,9{p;b};10{x;s/$/--/;x;G;p;b};:a;$p;N;21,$D;ba'
```

#### Example output:

***Note** On my Mac, with MacPorts, GNU `sed` is invoked as `gsed`. Apple's built-in `sed` is finicky about semi-colon separated expressions and requires multiple `-e` arguments. This should work on Apple's `sed`: `sed -ne'1,9{' -e'p;b' -e'}' -e'10{' -e'x;s/$/--/;x;G;p;b' -e'}' -e':a' -e'$p;N;21,$D;ba'` *

```
seq 100 | gsed -ne'1,9{p;b}' -e'10{x;s/$/--/;x;G;p;b}' -e':a;$p;N;21,$D;ba'

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
--
91
92
93
94
95
96
97
98
99
100
```

#### Explanation

`gsed -ne'` invoke `sed` without automatic printing pattern space

`-e'1,9{p;b}'` print the first 9 lines

`-e'10{x;s/$/--/;x;G;p;b}'` print line 10 with an appended '--' separator

`-e':a;$p;N;21,$D;ba'` print the last 10 lines

Comment: If you want to read exactly one line and *not* consume further input, btw, you can implement that yourself: `seq 100 | { read first; echo "$first"; tail -n1; }` does what you'd expect.

Comment: (BTW, I dispute the "should" in the question. If you can find a documented guarantee that the behavior described here breaks, I'd love to see it; the standard that `head` conforms to is [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/head.html) -- there are no obvious guarantees provided re: how much of stdin is consumed).

Comment: You an avoid this problem by using a single program to print both the first and last lines, e.g. `seq 100 | sed -n '1p; $p'`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I understand your position on "should". I've updated my answer to reflect that "should" is my opinion only. The fact that `head` does not guarantee to 'put back' unused bytes from stdin is, IMO, incorrect behavior and the specification should be updated and `head` modified.

Comment: There *is* no mechanism to "put back" content in bulk. You either read only one byte at a time and make things very slow (this is what the shell implementation of  `read` does, and why its performance is so bad), or you read in large blocks and consume more than you need.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I've updated my answer with a fuller sed script that prints more than just 1 line.

Comment: @parleer `seq 1 100 | sed -e '11,${:a;N;21,$D;ba}'` for a shorter and IMO simpler alternative. It prints the first and last 10 lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see the same behavior with GNU `head` and `tail` on Linux.

It depends on how much input `head -n1` consumes before it quits.  If `head` reads all of stdin before it quits, then there is nothing left for `tail` to read and `tail` produces no output.

Observe:

```
$ seq 10000 | (head -n1 ; cat ) | head
1

1861
1862
1863
1864
1865
1866
1867
1868
```

Here, we can see that `head -n1` consumes the first 1860 lines.  The `cat` command sees all the remaining input.

Why is that?  Observe how many bytes are in the first 1860 lines:

```
$ seq 1860 | wc
   1860    1860    8193
```

It's a reasonable guess that `head -n1` first reads 8kB of data from stdin, then prints the first line, and, seeing that it needs no more data, it quits.  The rest of stdin is available for any subsequent process.

So, with `seq 100` which produces less than 8kB output total, `head` reads all of stdin and leaves nothing for `tail` to read.  With `seq 10000` which produces more than 8kB, `head` will not read all the data in pipeline.  The data that it leaves will be available for `tail`.

As [Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy) points out, the details of this behavior are entirely implementation dependent and, upon any software upgrade, it may change.

Comment: Very interesting observation.

Comment: I'm selecting this as the answer because my question was *why* doesn't it work, and @John1024 provided an answer. I had thought it must be something of this nature and unfortunately the unreliability of head/tail implementation with pipes makes using them unacceptable. I've updated my answer with an `sed` script for anyone looking for a workable solution to the (separate) problem reading the first and last n lines of a stream.